# I can't open .png images in the blender 2D workspace in object mode

Tags: animation

I'm using Blender 3.3 with Win10. It's the first time I've used this version, and I can't open .png images in the 2D workspace. I am in Object Mode when this happens, and I check the images box in the filters options, but when I try to open a .png it gives me the error message *"file format not supported"*. This never happened in the last version of Blender that I used. I would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

The mistake I made was following the Blender 2.8 tutorials, since I'm using blender 3.3.

I couldn't find anything newer on Blender's site. I found the answer on Youtube, though, and the old way of opening a .png doesn't work.

You have to use the Edit menu to import the image as planes.

The old way was allowing images in the filter menu.

This makes no sense to me, because almost all images in the 2D workspace are, by default planes. Everything's a plane in the 2D environment, isn't it? I know you can import a 3D image into the 2D workspace, but it seems to me, that you shouldn't have to go to special steps to import a 2D image into the 2D workspace, the workspace should accept 2D images by default. Just a suggestion. I use a lot of clipart in my animations, and I'm sure I'm not the only one. It should be a simpler process to open a .png or.jpg.